Eigenvalues of Hecke operators for Siegel eigenforms are algebraic
Cross-posted from MSE (sorry about that, I now think it is more likely to get answer here).
Let $F$ be a Siegel modular form for $\text{Sp}_4(\mathbb{Z})$ of genus two. Let it also be an eigenform for all the Hecke operators $T_n$, $n\geq1$ (genus two).
Are the eigenvalues corresponding to these Hecke operators algebraic?
I know that they are real owing to the fact that the Hecke operators are self adjoint. I'm aware of this analogous question in the genus 1 case regarding elliptic modular form, where the heart of the proof is the fact that we can find a basis with integer Fourier coefficients. In the genus two case, I know that (read in text) the Fourier coefficients are algebraic, but we do not have nice relation (as in genus 1 case) between them and the Hecke eigenvalues.
Any help, reference or related information?

In the genus two case (at least for scalar-valued modular forms), you still have a basis with integer Fourier coefficients. Igusa proves that the ring of classical Siegel modular forms of degree 2 and level 1 is generated by 5 integral generators (2 Eisenstein series, 3 cusp forms). Moreover, this is also true over any $\mathbb{Z}[1/6]$-algebra. I hope this information helps.

How are you defining the Hecke operators?  If you have an operator given by an integral matrix, the eigenvalues are algebraic essentially by definition.
